# RegEx alternative to lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following text:

```
asdfasdf added Big Box of Chocolate Bars x9, Bottle of Beer x10, Empty Blood Bag x4 to the trade.
asdfasdf added Grenade x8, Pepper Spray x7 to the trade.
tasdf added Jacket x6 to the trade.
aasdfa added Banana Orchid x5 to the trade.
asdfasdas added Single Red Rose x4 to the trade.
dgfhdfggg added Bunch of Flowers x3 to the trade.
asdfax2sdfas added Blood Bag : A+ x2 to the trade.
asdasdasd added Empty Blood Bag x1 to the trade.
Monkey Plushie x10, Leather Gloves x12, Monkey Plushie X321
```

I want to capture the item names and the quantity, `Monkey Plushie x10`, `Single Red Rose x4`, etc.
At the moment I am using positive lookbehind to do it but it seems that it's not available on react native so I need an alternative to it. Best I got so far is `(?:added)(\s.+x\d+)` ...yes I am terrible at regex ...

Comment: Yes, it causes the app to crash with 'invalid regular expression' error on load. Works only on development, crashes when running on an actual phone, caught me by surprise too :)

Comment: Right, that's what I meant. Just woke up, sorry.

Comment: Do you need *just* the names and quantities from the whole text? You don't need to differentiate those on different lines?

Comment: I just need `item xQuantity` captured in an array element. End result should be an array-like  `['Blood Bag : A+ x2', 'Leather Gloves x12']` and so on, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split by newlines, then match the first two words in the line, while capturing the rest of the line (except the `to the trade` part, which we want to exclude, so match it normally). Then extract the captured group and split by a comma and a space:

```js
const input = `asdfasdf added Big Box of Chocolate Bars x9, Bottle of Beer x10, Empty Blood Bag x4 to the trade.
asdfasdf added Grenade x8, Pepper Spray x7 to the trade.
tasdf added Jacket x6 to the trade.
aasdfa added Banana Orchid x5 to the trade.
asdfasdas added Single Red Rose x4 to the trade.
dgfhdfggg added Bunch of Flowers x3 to the trade.
asdfax2sdfas added Blood Bag : A+ x2 to the trade.
asdasdasd added Empty Blood Bag x1 to the trade.`;
const output = input
  .split('\n')
  .flatMap(
    line => line
      .match(/\S+ \S+ (.*) to the trade\./)[1]
      .split(', ')
  );
console.log(output);
```

If you can't use `flatMap`, then spread into `concat` instead:

```js
const input = `asdfasdf added Big Box of Chocolate Bars x9, Bottle of Beer x10, Empty Blood Bag x4 to the trade.
asdfasdf added Grenade x8, Pepper Spray x7 to the trade.
tasdf added Jacket x6 to the trade.
aasdfa added Banana Orchid x5 to the trade.
asdfasdas added Single Red Rose x4 to the trade.
dgfhdfggg added Bunch of Flowers x3 to the trade.
asdfax2sdfas added Blood Bag : A+ x2 to the trade.
asdasdasd added Empty Blood Bag x1 to the trade.`;
const addedsArrOfArrs = input
  .split('\n')
  .map(
    line => line
      .match(/\S+ \S+ (.*) to the trade\./)[1]
      .split(', ')
  );
const output = [].concat(...addedsArrOfArrs);
console.log(output);
```

If you can't use Javascript string/array manipulation at all, you can use the regular expression

```
\b(?!.*added)\w[^,\n]*(?=.*x\d)x\d+
```

https://regex101.com/r/b6rYvA/1/

but that's ugly and a lot harder to understand at a glance, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I thought there might be some regex way of doing things without using js, code above fails with undefined for [1]. Got my own hacky solution, thanks anyway.

Comment: It would be possible to do this with regex alone, but it would be a *lot* uglier, so I'd prefer the JS-centered version

Comment: [`\b(?!.*added)\w[^,\n]*(?=.*x\d)x\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/b6rYvA/1)

Comment: I like the ugly version, it makes the rest of my code easier, thanks!

Comment: I've also decided to give it a try, so this is the solution that I'd come up with.
`var regExp = /(?<=added\s|\d+,\s)([\w:\+\s])+(x\d+)/g;`

Comment: @Konrud That depends on lookbehind, though, which (as OP said) is an issue - only new-ish browsers support it, unfortunately

Comment: @CertainPerformance you're totally right. I've overlooked it. Thanks. Then we can use something like this:
`var regExp = /(?!.*added)\b\w[^,\n]*x\d+/g;`